# Why does my batch file give an error if it has spaces in path?

Tags: java, windows, file, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a `.jar` file using a `.bat` file. But my Batch file gives an error when I have spaces in my path.
For e.g.

```
@echo off
java -jar %~dp0\..\new\myFile.jar %*
```

This are the contents of my batch file. I know that `%~dp0` will give the current **d**rive letter and **p**ath to my batch file and then `\..\` will go back to it's parent directory and then it will open the `new` directory and run the jar file from it.

But the problem here is if my path contains a space in it the batch file gives an error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\Vatsal
```

Assuming my path for `.jar` file is:

```
C:\Users\Vatsal Sura\myFolder\new\myFile.jar
```

and path for my `.bat` file is:

```
C:\Users\Vatsal Sura\myFolder\batch\batchFile.bat
```

Now if I move `myFolder` directly in `C:\`, which doesn't contain any spaces in it, then it won't give any error and the `.jar` file would run as expected.

I want to know why this is happening and what should I do to make spaces count in my path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the offending part in double quotes: `java -jar "%~dp0\..\new\myFile.jar" %*`

If the expansion is `C:\Users\Vatsal Sura\myFolder\new\myFile.jar`, then without quotes, `-jar` is only seeing up to the first space as it's argument (i.e. `-jar C:\Users\Vatsal`) and the remainder (`Sura\myFolder\new\myFile.jar`) is a completely different argument not related to the `-jar`

You need to make the shell/cmd see all of that as one argument. Double quotes will still allow any expansion to happen but everything within the quotes will be seen as a single item (the quotes won't be there when java sees it).

Comment: Yeah, this solved the issue but can you please explain it in a little bit more detail why it wasn't considering spaces in my path without the double quotes?

Comment: @VatsalSura, how is it supposed to know where the path ends and the arguments begin if you don't put quotes around the path.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understood it properly.

@Squashman I am new to batch programming and I didn't knew this so I am sorry if it was a silly mistake on my side.

Comment: @VatsalSura, this is not confined to just batch files. Many programming languages require this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is simple

Batch Is Simple Too,
Windows needed to create command Line, powershell, blah blah, and with its awesome features. However, Batch only runs on one programmed line of code, yes its confusing lol but when you write the code it is nothing compared to the binary. Batch is not too advanced and therefore does not process spaces when its in the *"heart"* of the command, like it i do this it literally has the same error however batch can tell the difference:

```
ec ho
```

(supposed to be echo)
anyways, a simple solution to your problem can be changing the encoding that your batch file is working on or just simply taking out the spaces on you directory.

Plus, don't use

```
%~dp0\
```

(it suKs)

Instead, to simplify this just do

```
@echo off
java -jar %CD%\new\myFile.jar %*
```

you don't have to even set %CD% to be anything it just automatically used the current directory.
*even with all this, your initial problem will not be solved. It may if you change the encoding (use notepad++ for that) but i hope you found this answer at least a little helpful to explain how this is working.

Comment: Please read the topic in the given URL [Why %cd% shouldn't be used](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=54333.0) for this program.